# Crash when I disable the "Global C-State Control" in BIOS?

Tags: bios, amd-ryzen

A new computer, the spec is Win10, Msi X670E ACE, 7950x3D.

After I disable the "Global C-State Control" in BIOS, the system whill randomly suddenly reboot in idle. It runs good when I am actively using the computer, gaming/working/watching YouTube. The problem is only appears when I leave the computer alone, go AFK.

I tried High performance/ Power Supply idle Control in typical current idle/ disable power down mode, rest of the setting in auto, it still crashes. Once It will continue crashing until I re-enable power down mode.

So, what should I do? Is the only way to increase the voltage? I am using AMD cpu for the first time, and no ideas for X3D.

Comment: "Global C-state Control" lets the BIOS turn off partly the CPU to conserve power. What does this have to do with increasing the voltage, or what is your real problem?

Comment: I know this is weird and unreasonable, but it really happening on me.
This problem only appear when I afk, so it pretty sure the problem is on  idle power.
But I can't pinpoint exactly where, so I'm also looking for someone with experience

Comment: What is the reason for disabling "Global C-State Control" in the first place?